# Adjoint of momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

In position basis, we have,

$$\langle x \mid \hat p \mid \Psi(t) \rangle = -\imath  \hbar \frac{\partial{\langle x \mid \Psi(t) \rangle}}{\partial{x}} $$

Now I know $\hat{p}$ is a Hermitian operator which should be self adjoint.

The self adjoint operators are said to satisfy :

$$\langle A \psi \mid \phi \rangle = \langle \psi \mid A \phi \rangle$$

But I failed to workout the following :

$$ \langle x \mid \hat{p}^\dagger \mid \Psi(t) \rangle$$

For ladder operator $\hat{a}$ I found $\hat{a}^\dagger$ by conjugating in position basis. And clearly $\hat{a}$ is not Hermitian because 
$$ \hat{a}^\dagger \neq \hat{a}$$ in position basis. And thus $\hat{a}$ does not correspond to any observable.

But $\hat{p}$ is Hermitian. But it seems, at position basis, complex conjugating $\hat{p}$ gives a different object.

Where am I making a mistake here?

**EDIT:**

After posting the question I found some inconsistencies in my argument.

$$\hat a = \frac {\hat x}{\sqrt {\frac {2 \hbar}{m \omega}}} + \frac {i  \hat p}{\sqrt {2 \hbar m \omega}}$$

is not a **representation** in any basis. It's just an operator relation with some scaling factor.

whereas $$-i \hbar \frac {\partial}{\partial x} $$ is a **representation** of $\hat p$ in position $x$ basis.

So they should not be comparable.

But i still want to know what $\hat{p}^\dagger$ is in position $x$ basis.

I just falsely took a wrong example.

Comment: Where and why do the ladder operators come into the game?

Comment: see my edit. I was comparing falsely. I just asked how should i get a adjoint momentum operator in position basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\hat{p}$ is Hermitian and Hermitian operators $O$ satisfy, by definition,

$$\hat{O} = \hat{O}^\dagger$$

Adjoint is not a synonym for complex conjugate. $\hat{p} = -i\hbar \nabla \rightarrow +i\hbar \nabla^\dagger \rightarrow -i\hbar \nabla =\hat{p}^\dagger$, but $\hat{p} \neq \hat{p}^*$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any general rule for getting adjoint for non matrix operators?

Comment: @Aftnix $\hat{p}$ can be represented as a matrix, just an infinite-dimensional one. You might find my answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46380/is-h-h-sloppy-notation-or-really-just-incorrect-for-hermitian-operators/46409#46409) useful.

Comment: @Aftnix: What do you mean by non matrix operators?

Comment: after going through linear algebra resources i found exact answer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The adjoin of the differential operator $\nabla^\dagger = -\nabla$ can be proved by integration by part.