# The hermitian conjugate of anti-linear operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, complex-numbers

Some quantum mechanics books tell us that the definitions of hermitian are

> If $\langle\psi|A\phi\rangle=\langle B\psi|\phi\rangle$ for linear operators, then $B=A^\dagger$
>
> If $\langle\psi|C\phi\rangle=\langle D\psi|\phi\rangle^*$ for [anti-linear](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antilinear.html) operators, then $D=C^\dagger$

1. **Why are definitions different between linear operators and anti-linear operators ?**
2. **Are they equivalent to the definition $Q^\dagger=(Q^T)^*$ in linear algebra, where $Q^T$ is the transpose of $Q$ ?**

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45227/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are defintions different between linear operators and anti-linear operators?

Let $\lambda$ be any complex scalar.  Then
$$\langle \psi|C(\lambda \phi)\rangle = \langle\psi|\overline \lambda C\phi\rangle = \overline \lambda\langle\psi|C\phi\rangle$$

by the definition of anti-linearity.  If we use the definition we normally use for linear operators, then we would find
$$\langle \psi | C(\lambda \phi)\rangle = \langle D\psi|\lambda \phi\rangle$$
but also that
$$\overline \lambda \langle\psi|C\phi\rangle = \overline \lambda\langle D \psi|\phi\rangle = \langle D\psi|\overline \lambda \phi\rangle$$

which is inconsistent.  Using the slightly modified definition fixes this problem.

> Are they equivalent to the definition $Q^\dagger=(Q^T)^∗$ in linear algebra, where $Q^T$ is the transpose of $Q$?

The first one is, yes.

If you imagine two arbitrary column vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ and matrices $A$ and $B$, then the first definition becomes
$$\mathbf x^\dagger A \mathbf y = (B\mathbf x)^\dagger \mathbf y \implies B=A^\dagger$$

where the dagger denotes conjugate transposition.  But this should be clear, since
$$(B\mathbf x)^\dagger = \mathbf x^\dagger B^\dagger$$
so
$$\mathbf x^\dagger A \mathbf y= \mathbf x^\dagger B^\dagger \mathbf y$$
If that equality holds for all $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$, then $A=B^\dagger \iff A^\dagger = B$.

The case of anti-linear operators is a bit more subtle because an anti-linear operator cannot be written as a matrix all by itself; it has to be a matrix plus a complex conjugation, and therefore cannot be realized if we restrict ourselves to standard matrix algebra.