# Can I see $Ψ^∗(x,t)$ as a linear functional which can be aplied on wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, complex-numbers

Let's say I have a wavefunction $\Psi(x,t) = A e^{i(kx−ωt)}$. Now I complex conjugate it which gives me $\Psi^∗(x,t)$.

My first question is: Does $\Psi^∗(x,t)$ live in the dual of a Hilbert space?

My second question is: Can I see $\Psi^∗(x,t)$ as a linear functional which can be applied on wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ in order to get a number? Thanks

Comment: "Does the Ψ∗(x,t) live in the dual of a Hilbert space?" Almost. It's linear w.r.t. real scalars, but not w.r.t. complex ones.
"Can I see Ψ∗(x,t) as a linear functional which can be applied on wave function Ψ(x,t) and I get a number?" Isn't that the definition of the dual space?

Comment: You can define an anti-linear map $C:L^2\longrightarrow L^2$ by $C:\psi \mapsto \bar\psi$, cf. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246743/complex-conjugate-of-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation). But note that on a general Hilbert space complex conjugation is not canonical, as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510383/is-complex-conjugation-operator-hermitian).

Comment: Reminder that answers should be posted as answers