# How to prove this identity for the complex conjugate of linear operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra

I want to prove the following identity:

$$\langle v|\Omega^{\dagger}|u\rangle = \langle u|\Omega | v \rangle^*$$

How should I go about this? I believe I can prove it when $\Omega$ is hermitian, but I do not know how to prove it in general.

Comment: What's the definition of $\Omega^\dagger$?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43069/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216846/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex conjugate operation distributes in an inverse order. Let a, b, c be some numbers that the conjugate action can act. Then,
$$
(abc)^* = c^* b^* a^*
$$
For a general case where a, b, c are not numbers but could be state, operator, etc., such that the product is a number, then one needs to use Hermitian conjugate, of course. So, 
$$\langle u | \Omega | v \rangle^* = | v\rangle^\dagger \Omega^\dagger \langle u |^\dagger $$
and of course, due to the fact that the conjugate of a bra is a ket and vice versa, one can conclude the proof.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition. It is $$(\Omega^\dagger v, u)  = (v, \Omega u) = (\Omega u, v) ^* $$