# What is the adjoint of a ket-bra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

Let $T$ be a linear operator, then we can consider the rank-one operator

$$\vert Tx \rangle \langle y \vert.$$

I am wondering what is its adjoint operator, is it

$$\vert y \rangle \langle T^*x \vert?$$

Comment: Replace $T^*$ for $T$ and your sipppsition is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43069/difficulties-with-bra-ket-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any two vectors $|v\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$, the adjoint of $|w\rangle\langle v|$ is $|v\rangle\langle w|$.

So, the adjoint of $|Tx\rangle \langle y|$ is $|y\rangle \langle Tx|$.

Comment: It might also be helpful to note that if $T|x\rangle = |Tx\rangle$ then $\langle Tx| = \langle x|T^†$

Comment: But why does that property hold true in the first place?